# MARIADB - Error while sending QUERY packet (not max_allowed_packet)

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm having an issue with a PHP7 script saving data to a database (MariaDB). The script worked fine on a previous hosting package, but not on my new VPS.

```
Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=1208 in ...
```

Other threads caused me to look at settings, but my settings are:

- max_allowed_packet = 1GB
- wait_timeout = 10

I've reviewed the issue further and found there is nothing wrong with the query itself (it executes fine in phpMyAdmin).

**It seems to be something to do with executing two queries in close succession without closing the connection (the second one fails)**.

The same script ran fine on the old hosting, it must be a setting - does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks,
Ben

MariaDB config (/etc/my.cnf):

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1GB
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

innodb_file_per_table

max_connections=70
max_user_connections=30
wait_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=50
long_query_time=5
```

Comment: You already have the answer `It seems to be something to do with executing two queries in close succession without closing the connection (the second one fails).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 minute after asking it, I've answered my own question. This was the issue:

```
wait_timeout=10
```

My previous hosting configuration had **=180** which make my poorly written script work. Under the **=10** it's just not long enough for the task to complete. I have lengthened it to **180** now but should really add handle for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue and it's super annoying. The queries are running fast, but at some point they keep hanging and locks up for no reason explainable.
I have it on 60 seconds and don't think increasing it is a good solution.

Does this mean that the script takes over 60 seconds and the database is gone?

However I have noticed the SQL's are "deadlocking", because they hang in SHOW PROCESSLIST. I only use SELECT + JOIN. So the SQL are the issue... but when I run them they are quick... it's so weeeird.

You said it's the connection not being closed, but that makes no sense. Connection is closed automatically.