# How to troubleshoot and fix database errors after transferring Wordpress website?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Please assist with troubleshooting the following errors for the Wordpress Database.

I am unable to update the Menus, Slider Revolution or make any updates.

Attempted fixes:

1. Deactivated and re-activated all plugins and themes
2. Updated all themes and plugins
3. Completed a Database clean up
4. Checked wp-config to make certain all database settings are correct
5. Checked all php config options to make sure all sizes are increase i.e max_post_size etc
6. Contacted hosting company to increase the packet size but they cannot do this.

The errors received are as follows:

```
PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=25614 in /home/waynebbfsafety/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2033

PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=25614 in /home/waynebbfsafety/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2033

PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=4904 in /home/waynebbfsafety/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2033

PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/waynebbfsafety/public_html/wp-content/uploads/fusion-builder-avada-pages/data.zip): No such file or directory in /home/waynebbfsafety/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avada-functions.php on line 878

PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/waynebbfsafety/public_html/wp-content/uploads/fusion-builder-avada-pages/data.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/waynebbfsafety/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avada-functions.php on line 879
```

Comment: That's quite a specific and unusual error msg, did you try searching for it?  It looks like there are plenty of results with answers right here on SO, have you been through those?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398490/mariadb-error-while-sending-query-packet-not-max-allowed-packet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198087/error-while-sending-query-packet-pid-9565 ... My guess is the last 2 errors are just consequences of the first problem, so the `QUERY` error is the one to look at.

Comment: Yes I have researched and also checked the related articles for this error but nothing helps. The host company says they cannot increase the packet size due the website being on a shared server.

Comment: What does `after transferring Wordpress website` mean, exactly?  Do you know what `fusion-builder-avada-pages/data.zip` is, or why something is looking for it?

Comment: Hi, by transfer I meant from one web host to another. Yes I did find fusion builder avada pages/data.zip but that did not solve the problem. Eventually the website was re-uploaded to the new web host server and that did the trick! Thank you